# Why won't StratusForms Submit an Update

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, spservices, stratusforms

My project is running an `update` `batch Command` via `SPServices` and I am getting error `0x80020005` in return, but I can't seem to figure out what field or value is throwing the error, so I'm hoping someone can point out to me what I can do to track down the error; I have no idea where to look.

I am using [StratusForms](http://www.itunity.com/community/stratusforms) (formerly Forms-7).

Here is the `StratusForms` Save Function:

```
$.fn.StratusFormsSubmit = function (options) {
    var opt = $.extend({}, {
        listName: "",
        StratusFormsDataField: "StratusFormsData",
        validateForm: true,
        completefunc: null,
        errorOffsetTop: 20,
        errorOffsetLeft: 25
    }, options);
    var $this = this;

    if (gStratusFormsEncrptForm && gStratusFormsDecryptFailed) {
        alert("Cannot save form that was not properly decrypted. Please refresh the form and enter the correct decryption key.");
        return;
    }
    return this.each(function () {

        if (opt.validateForm) {
            if (($this).StratusFormsValidate({
                errorOffsetTop: opt.errorOffsetTop,
                errorOffsetLeft: opt.errorOffsetLeft
            })) {
                saveForm($this, opt.listName, opt.completefunc, opt.StratusFormsDataField);
            }
            else {
                alert("Please fix form errors and re-submit!");
            }
        } else {
            saveForm($this, opt.listName, opt.completefunc, opt.StratusFormsDataField);
        }

    });
};
```

Here is the `StratusForms` `SPServices` function which is serving the error message where I can see the error code:

```
$.fn.StratusFormsSaveForm = function (listName, formID, StratusFormsValuePairs, saveCompleteFunc) {

        var batchCommand = "New";
    var ID = 0;
    if (formID != undefined && formID != 0) {
        batchCommand = "Update";
        ID = formID;
    }

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        listName: listName,
        batchCmd: batchCommand,
        ID: ID,
        valuepairs: StratusFormsValuePairs,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            var errorCode = $(xData.responseXML).find("ErrorCode").text();


            if (errorCode != "0x00000000") {
             /////////////////////////HERE IS THE ERROR CODE I RECEIVE
                alert("An error occurred creating or updating your form. Please check your entries and try again.\r\nerrorcode:" + errorCode); 
                return;
            }
            else if (Status == "Error") {
                alert("Unable to communicate with Sharepoint Server!");
                return;
            }
            //alert(xData.responseXML.xml);
            var newId = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_ID");
            if (saveCompleteFunc !== null) {
                saveCompleteFunc(newId);
            }
            //           SaveSuccessful(newId);

        }
    });

}
```

And here is my call:

```
function helpdesksubmit(){
    //also passes in the x and y offset of error messages for elements; this allows you to change their location in reference to the form field
    $(helpdesk.EntryFormID).StratusFormsSubmit({
        listName: helpdesk.TicketList,
        errorOffsetTop: 10,
        errorOffsetLeft: 5,
        completefunc: function(id) { 
            alert(thisUserName + ", the save was successful.\r\nRequest ID = " + id);
            loadFormID(id);
        }
     });    
}
```

How do I track this down?

**[update]**

So, I am able to CREATE new items, but I cannot update them.  In the debugger I can see that the batchCommand is correct, the ID has a correct value, the listName is correct and the valuepairs are loaded.  I'm guessing the problem lie with the valuepairs somehow.

pair: Title - one
stratus...ices.js (line 314)

```
pair: ticketcat - Other
stratus...ices.js (line 314)
pair: ticketsubcat - I'm Stuck
stratus...ices.js (line 314)
pair: Description - worksx
stratus...ices.js (line 314)
pair: StratusFormsData - {StratusFormsRepeatable: [],helpdesktitlefield:"one",TicketCategory:"Other",TicketSubCategory:"I'm Stuck",HelpDeskActionSelector:"Edit Existing Ticket",HelpDeskItemSelector:"4",Description:"worksx"};
```

The only thing that seems out of whack is in the StratusFormsData field - the `HelpDeskItemSelector` and `HelpDeskActionSelector` do not send values to the list and so should not really have any data to save in the json field.  If these fields do not send/receive data to the list (they are static controls) then they don't need to be saved.  I wonder if this is the problem?  If so, then this is a bug in StratusForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem.  My underlying list had a field type of "[Filtered Lookup](https://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)".  When I deleted this column then speservices was able to submit the data to the other columns just fine.  I'm not sure, but maybe it had a "required" flag set on the field.

I never did figure out how to trace what the actual error was in spservices.